# Are the unions of homeomorphic disjoint open sets $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ homeomorphic as well?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces such that $X=\bigcup X_n$ and $Y=\bigcup Y_n$, where $\{X_n\}_n$ and $\{Y_n\}_n$ are sequences of disjoint open sets of $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Show that, if $X_n$ is homeomorphic to $Y_n$ for all indexes $n$, then $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$.

I'm actually kind of skeptical of this statement. However, this is my progress:
As $X_n$ is homeomorphic to $Y_n$, there must exists an homeomorphism $f_n:X_n\to Y_n$ corresponding to the index $n$. We define the following mapping
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} f_n(x) \text{ ; } & x\in X_n\end{cases}.$$
It's not too hard to show that this is a biyective map. However, I don't believe it's bicontinuous, for with the information available we can only know that it maps open sets $X_n$ to open sets $Y_n$ (and we can say the same about their unions). But can we say anything about the images of subsets of each $X_n$, or the preimages of subsets of each $Y_n$?

It could be that my choice for $f$ is wrong, but I'm now looking for a counterexample or a hint in the right direction to prove the statement. Any ideas?

Comment: If $X_n$ are a disjoint sets of open sets, then yes, by definition, $X$ is topologically the disjoint union of the $X_i.$

Comment: It's clear that $f(x)$ is continuous, and it's also clear that the inverse $g(x):=f_n^{-1}(y)$ for $y\in Y_n$ is continuous.

Comment: @KentaS Could you expand as to why $f$ is open (or equivalently, why is $g$ continuous)? It doesn't click to me because of this: take $A\subseteq X$. This subset may not necessarily be one of the $X_n$, but it will be generated by a collection $\{A_i\}_i$ of subsets $A_i\subseteq X_i$. Thus, we have $A=\bigcup_i A_i$, which only lands us on $f(A)=\bigcup_i f(A_i)$. This would be good if we knew the $A_i$ were open, but do we know that? Or am I approaching this wrongly?

Comment: Actually, this depends on what you mean by disjoint. If you just mean for all $m\ne n$ the sets $X_m$ and $X_n$ are disjoint then this is not enough (discrete countable set vs. $\mathbb Q$). If you mean something stronger, that the $X_n$ are open subsets of $X$, then you are OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a comment confirming that my choice of $f$ was indeed bicontinuous, I noticed that what I was missing was that when we take an open set $A\subseteq X$ and write it as $A=\bigcup_i A_i$, with $A_i\subseteq X_i$, we can see that $A_i=A\cap X_i$, an intersection of open sets. This means that $A_i$ is open in $X$. This should be enough of a "hint" for anyone else struggling with this problem.